# how are Visual c++ runtime dlls found?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I run a firefox with certain proprietary plugins on a variety of computers, some of them from customers. I need to be able to do so without installing (admin rights etc), so I created a virtualized version of this using spoon. This works like a charm in 99% of cases (from xp to win8), but there is this 1%...
In this 1% case (a win8 64 bit machine), on this one specific computer, this happens (I analyzed with sysinternals procmon):

- The firefox plugin container crashes, shortly after it loads msvcrt7.dll from the system. At this point, it has not tried to load any proprietary plugin dll. The plugincontainer uses msvcrt100.dll, my prop plugin msvcrt8.dll
- on my win8 machine, it loads msvcrt8.dll at this very point and goes on and works
- I made sure the virtual firefox does not load any other plugins. Actually, even the non-virtual ff loads no plugins at all, except the ones that come with it (flash disabled, however)
- I removed and reinstalled all msvcrt runtimes I found on the system
- I analyzed the plugin container dependencies using the dependency walker *in the virtual environment* - no dependency on msvcrt7 was shown (just msvcrt100 as expected)
- I was able to install the non-virtual plugin on this machine and it worked, btw

I am clueless now.

- Can anybody point me to a guide how the correct version of msvcrt is located?
- any ideas how to continue my quest?

Thank you!

Comment: Get Process Monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx set the filter to firefox, load up your plugin and see what file firefox is looking for.  It could be something with a .2.cfg.  This is the configuration file.  You may need to set up a configuration file to tell firefox where to find the dll http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kza1yk3a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of Sysinternals, but this use was new for me